# How can I post a XML string to my local API using mocha testing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, mocha.js, chai

I'm running a unit test for an endpoint that supposed to get an xml in a POST method using Mocha testing.
I've been searching for an answer on google but didn't find the right answer for my needs.
I need to POST an xml and not a json.
My endpoint converts the xml to json but it must receive an xml originally.

```
describe('doctoemail', function () {
    it("doctoemail", function (done) {
        request(app).post('/doctoemail/')
            .send(

// this is the xml im trying to send.

                `<urn:Document_IN>

        <urn:MailProperties>

        <urn:somedata>iamdata</urn:somedata>

                </urn:MailProperties>

                </urn:Document_IN>`

            )
            .end(function (err, res) {

                expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(200);// checks statuscode 200 = success
                console.log(res.text);
                expect(res.text).match(/document number/) // search for a known part of the document body
                done();
            })

    })
})
```

Comment: What does `request` come from? Do you use `chai-http` or `supertest`?